# How to merge two sculpted meshes?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, 3d-printing

Is it possible to merge two sculpted meshes?
If you want to make a 3d printable mesh, you want to make it hollow... so you copy the mesh and scale it down, inwards. Then you make faces between those two meshes... Is this realistic to make with an complex sculpted mesh, or should this be done, before you make the complex sculpting? Or should I retopology?
Also I sculpted the face/head and the hair in two seperate meshes, also the eyes are seperate... how do I efficient merging all those meshes into one?
Many thanks and happy modeling :)

Comment: Not sure I follow you "make faces" bit. Hollow objects don't need to be filled with faces that wouldn't be visible from the outside anyway. When I want to make something hollow, I typically add a "Solidify" modifier (and apply it, if necessary).

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Once you have everything combined in a single mesh, you need to make sure that the normals of the internal mesh are pointing in, and the normals of the outer mesh are pointing out.

Comment: It's possible to use Sculpt Tools addon for that, see example video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTQNGWawAwo

Comment: I think boolean should be preferred for joining for 3D printing

Answer (score 7):

You may use a ***Direct Union*** option of a ***BoolTool*** add on.

Activate it in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

In my case I have four objects with different vertex count. Some of them were sculpted, some of them not.
[image]

In *Object Mode* select all the objects and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num+</kbd> (or press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type 'direct'-->***Direct Union***). 
[image]

After this operation you'll achieve a joined mesh ready for sculpting.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can join multiple objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Just letting you know this was flagged as "low-quality because of its length and content."

Comment: My answer was flagged? Or the question?

Comment: The answer. It might have been an auto-flag because of it's length

Comment: I wouldn't flag it. But I tried it and I think it's not so good for 3d printing. The topology of the meshes isn't changed (I don't know if an export to stl gets them as one object) and you get faces in the inside, you don't want to print, because you can't see them. But I discovered the Boolean modifier with the Option Union, that does the trick.

Comment: Should I delete this answer then? I feel the question could be more concise, which would help make for a more focused answer.

Comment: That's also not the answer for this question, joining two objects into one won't merge them and doesn't do any good for 3D printing.

Answer (score 1):

When 3D printing a closed "water tight" object, don't worry about making it "hollow"  Just take your single, sculpted mesh, and export it as a stl.  The slicer program will fill this with a grid to support (this is what the infill % setting does).

If you really are keen making something "hollow", just copy paste, scale down a bit, and then boolean subtract.

If you are having with the boolean operation, I suggest you use the Remesh modifier first.

Answer (score 1):

Well just for the 'merging two meshes'. The best way I found is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (join meshes)
- on *Sculpt Mode* with *F Snake Hook* Brush, mix the extremes of the two meshes until you make a kind a "soup" with it
- smooth it out with the *F Smooth* Brush.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible! I had the same question.

To do so, you can use a boolean modifier to create a Union between the two meshes. The two meshes will join beautifully with no internal faces and you can smooth out the seams (may need to re-enable dynotopo) to create a single mesh. I got this information from the following youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-aQHMIYapI

Tested it in Blender 2.78 without issue. Make sure to move/delete the original piece you merged after applying the modifier.