# Connect sculpted sub-terrain to create tunnels?

Tags: sculpting

I wish to create sculpted tunnels, more specifically connecting two or more adjacent inward faces with a tunnel.  I am open to other solutions as long as it accomplishes the goal of creating a tunnel.
[image: Sculpted_Plane]

Comment: did you consider the possibility to create regular geometry "tunnel" maps first, and later sculpt them to become less perfect and regular?

Comment: @m.ardito The image above is to illustrate the concept, I'm actually trying to update a much more complex piece.  In the future I could attempt to do that, yes, but it's not a solution to my current problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it deleting some vertices for both sculpted elements and join them using faces (with the *bridge tool* or *F2* e.g.), then resculpt the joint, but it may be time consuming. I recommend you to use a ***Direct Union*** option of a ***BoolTool*** add on.

Activate it in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

In *Edit Mode* select a fragment of your element and separate it with <kbd>P</kbd>-->*Selection*.
[image]

Enter *Sculpt Mode* and join elements using *Snake Hook* brush e.g.
[image]

In *Object Mode* select both separated objects and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num+</kbd> (or press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *'direct'*).
[image]

It'll merge your sculpted mesh, so it'll be ready for sculpting. Then you can smooth the joint's transition using *Smooth* brush e.g. and sculpt some detail there.
[image]

Comment: I enabled bool tool then I saved, restarted blender, and checked again to be sure but direct yields no results and  Shift+Ctrl+Numplus gives me an error that says:

location <unkown location>:-1

RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.convert.poll() failed, context is incorrect.


Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I use it often and there are no problems with it. You may try @Thomas Pendergrass 's answer though (which uses a **Boolean Modifier**): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-to-merge-two-sculpted-meshes If it won't help you, feel free to ask a separate question about your issue.