# Is there a way to add a mesh to another without reseting sculpt data?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I've been sculpting a head, and when I got to the ear, I thought I'd make it its own object so that I could focus on it without the rest. Problem is, when I try to add the ear mesh to the head using Join, it resets the sculpt data. Is there a way to join the two meshes without this happening?

Comment: Maybe this one will help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-to-merge-two-sculpted-meshes

Comment: @PaulGonet In that example the sculpted meshes have had the Multires applied. I was hoping to join the base meshes so I can continue sculpting upon them.